# Unclear Infinite Integration by parts: $\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, integration-by-parts

I came across this example:

$$\int_0^{+\infty}xe^{-x} \ dx$$

I calculated it like this:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} xe^{-x} \  dx =  \left[ -xe^{-x} \right]_0^{+ \infty} - \int_0^{+ \infty} e^{-x}dx $$

$$ 0 - \left[ e^{-x} \right]^{+\infty}_0 = 0-0 = 0$$

$$ lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{e^x}\biggr\vert^\beta_0 = \lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\beta}{e^\beta} \quad L'H \\ lim_{\beta \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{e^\beta} = 0 \\ $$

But my sample solution says:

$$\int^{\infty}_0 xe^{-x} dx = \left[ - \frac{x}{e^x}-e^{-x}\right]\biggr\vert^\infty_0 = 0-0+1 = 1$$

I dont understand where the $1$ comes from, my understanding is that the limit of that function should go to zero but instead a $1$ appears.

Can someone clear this up ?

Comment: Note that $e^{0}=1$

Comment: ...in $0-[e^{-x}]_0^{+\infty}$

Comment: I also suspect you've made a typo, but this is not a problem because you seem to have fixed it later:
$$\int_0^{+\infty} xe^{-x} \  dx =  \left[ -xe^{-x} \right]_0^{+ \infty} \color{red}{+} \int_0^{+ \infty} e^{-x}dx$$

Comment: @projectilemotion oops, thanks for the catch, totally missed that. post an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you seem to have made a typo, but this is not a problem because you seem to have fixed it after integrating $e^{-x}$:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{+\infty} xe^{-x} \  dx &=  \left[ -xe^{-x} \right]_0^{+ \infty} \color{red}{+} \int_0^{+ \infty} e^{-x}dx \\&=\left[ -xe^{-x} \right]_0^{+ \infty}-\left[e^{-x}\right]_0^{+\infty}\\&=0-\left[e^{-x}\right]_0^{+\infty} \tag{1}\end{align}$$

---

Apart from that, the only mistake you made is when evaluating the right-hand side of $(1)$. Note that $e^0\neq 0$, but $e^0=1$, hence giving:
$$\int_0^{+\infty} xe^{-x}~dx=0-(0-1)=1$$

Comment: wait I'm a litle bit confused, I just looked up the definition of integration by parts and it says to subtract the two parts, but you add them together, which confuses me. can you explain ?

Comment: Integration by parts states that:
$$\int u~dv=uv-\int v~du$$
In your case, $u=x$ and $dv=e^{-x}~dx$. Note that as a result, $v=\color{red}{-}e^{-x}$, since:
$$\int e^{-x}~dx=-e^{-x}+C$$

Comment: ah yes makes sense